# Handeling INFO with try-except

Tags: windows, task, python-3.7

I'm using subprocess.call to kill a task.
Following the pythonic way of [asking forgivness](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html#asking-for-permission-instead-of-forgiveness), I use it in a try-except formation.
Yet, I do not know how to catch the INFO - as it is not an error per-se'

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.call(['TASKKILL', '/FI', f"IMAGENAME eq MyEXE.exe", '/F'])
except all:
    pass
```

I still get

```
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria
```

How can I suppress the INFO message?

P.S. (I don't wish to shut all output, or TASKLIST to check if the task exists before I kill the task)

Comment: In general, if you want an exception to handle, use `subprocess.run` with `check=True`, or `subprocess.check_call`, or `subprocess.check_output`. These raise a`subprocess.CalledProcessError` exception if the process returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Unfortunately taskkill.exe doesn't fail with a non-zero exit status if it doesn't find a matching process. So you'd have to use `subprocess.run` with `capture_output=True` and parse the `stdout` value of the `CompletedProcess` result for `b'No tasks running'`, or use `subprocess.check_output` to get the stdout bytes directly. This message is probably localized text, however, so it's a fragile implementation.

Comment: Thank you @ErykSun, The `subprocess.check_output` **works** (the other two options still produced the INFO:...)

Comment: `p = subprocess.run(['taskkill.exe', '/fi', 'imagename eq myexe.exe', '/f'], capture_output=True)` should work. The output will be in `p.stdout`.